# using bootstrap 4 flex grid to get a layout for laptop and desktop

Tags: bootstrap-4

i'm new to the bs4 grid system and i need a layout for desktop and mobile version

The code i tried is

```
<section class="banner-masonry">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 px-0">
          <a href="javascript:;"><img src="image1" class="img-fluid"/></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 px-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12 px-0">
                      <a href="javascript:;"><img src="image2" class="img-fluid"/></a>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 px-0" id="grey">
                       <a href="javascript:;"><img src="image 3" class="img-fluid"/></a>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-6 px-0" id="grey">
                      <a href="javascript:;"><img src="image 4" class="img-fluid"/></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But its not working...I will attach both desktop and mobile layout below

Desktop - [Deesktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrqYh.jpg)

Mobile - [Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSkox.jpg)

Any help would be appreciatable, thanks in advance.....

the desktop and mobile ouput im getting is something like this, see below the links

Desktop - [desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoAai.jpg)

Mobile - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T53Zq.jpg)

Comment: can you explain, what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: it seems like you just need to adjust the spacing. for that you can use the 'id' and custonize it using css

Comment: I'm not sure, but the result should be as the links i provided